# What is the reason(s) NOT to include google fonts in 2 import rule

Tags: css, wordpress, import

I've seen some argue, explicit or implicit, that you should not import fonts in style.css via @import rule.

What are the main reasons you should not do that?

Comment: @import rule in general is considered an old practice that is bad nowdays. Anyway, this site is about question specific to WordPress and your question is not. I vote to migrate to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons

- It is slower than the recommended way of using `wp_enqueue_scripts`
- Child themes and plugins cannot remove these styles
- Dependencies cannot be set and styles cannot be loaded conditionally
- Overriding these styles sometimes require the use of `!important` which is not really recommended in CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer - which also show why it's a specific WordPress question.